# Right way to restart Oracle 12c Server with pluggable databases

Tags: oracle

I am new to oracle. I installed Oracle 12c on windows with a pluggable database on a test VM. Everything was working fine. After the installation I was able to connect via EM Express on port 5500, via SQLPlus and via SQL Developer.

Them I restarted the server (windows shutdown and restart) and nothing worked. After some serious reading and a lot of trial and error I was able to connect again by starting the listener, the container database and the pluggable database. Also I had to restart the Listener service via the windows services application.

Now I have a couple of questions. Given my environment what is the recommended procedure to restart my oracle server? Is shutting down windows OK or should I shut down the oracle databases and listener before shutting down windows? What is the right startup process after a restart? Startup the container and pluggable databases and them the listener or vice versa?

**All of those questions translate into just one: What is the right way (procedure and order) to shutdown and restart a windows server with Oracle 12c that has a pluggable database?**

I have been reading about all those aspects but given my inexperience I haven’t found a guide about what to do in what order and why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm guessing you have a windows service you can just stop - but maybe not. Your instance should have come back up when the server rebooted. Start here in the docs http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/start.htm#ADMIN11156

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am reading it carefully. However I had almost the same experience with a different VM with Linux. So I am guessing that some configuration besides the wizard based installation is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to propose my findings as an answer. I have tested these procedures and they seem to work fine.

*NOTE: The whole experiment was done on Windows Server 2012 R2, however based on my readings I would say most of it applies to Linux too.*

**Shutdown**

1. Shutdown the Oracle Database Instance to ensure that everything close cleanly
   https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/instance.htm#ADMQS052
   http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-stop-an-oracle-12c-database.html
2. Shutdown Windows Server

**Restart**

1. Start Windows Server
2. Start the Listener
   https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/network.htm#ADMQS044
3. Start the Database instance
   https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/instance.htm#ADMQS052

**Remarks**

**Restarting the Windows Server should do everything automatically** but there are a couple of remarks.

1. **Starting the Oracle Services on windows is not the same as starting the database instance. However they are configured by default to behave that way.** Oracle Administration Assistant for Windows can be used to determine what exactly happens with the database instance when the Oracle Services are restarted. 
   https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTQRF/admin.htm#i1006074
2. Linux can also be configured to start the Oracle Database automatically using scripts. **Oracle Restart was recommend in previous versions to accomplish this but is now deprecated.**
   https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UNXAR/strt_stp.htm#UNXAR150
   http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/restart.htm#ADMIN12708
3. This step is no longer necessary, see below: **If a pluggable database was configured during installation it should be manually started after restarting the oracle services.**
   https://web.archive.org/web/20180911225755/http://blog.contractoracle.com:80/2013/06/oracle-12c-need-to-start-container-and.html

Do note: **The 12.1.0.2 patchset introduced the ability to preserve the startup state of PDBs through a CDB restart.** This is done using the ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE command with the OPEN and SAVE STATE options.
http://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-startup-and-shutdown-cdb-and-pdb-12cr1.php